# Error al llamar a digest

Tags: angularjs

Mi archivo js:

```
$scope.loadOptions = function(email) {
   //aqui llamo a varios métodos y al final tengo voy asignando valores a variables
   $scope.$apply();
}
```

mi archivo html:

```
<div ng-init="loadOptions">
  <textarea class="w95" name="tinymce${it?.id}" id="tinymce${it?.id}">{{qualitative[${it.id}]}}</textarea>
</div>
```

Obtengo este error :

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

El valor del textarea hay veces que me lo muestra y otras no, no se si esta relacionado que tengo que actulizar los valores

Comment: Eliminaste `$scope.$apply()` como sugerí?

Comment: si pero hay veces que me muestra el valor y otras no

Comment: El error que tenias ya fue solucionado. Eso seria otra pregunta ;)

Answer (score 2):

[$apply forza la ejecucion de un $digest() por debajo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest). La directiva ngClick ya tiene un evento `$apply()` corriendo y no puedes correr 2 `$digest()` al mismo tiempo.

Solo debes de utilizar `$apply()` cuando estas fuera del contexto de angularjs. Digase fuera del controlador o en un codigo externo:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  angular.element($("#mi-otro-boton-dentro-de-un-controlador").scope().$apply();
});
```

El evento click de jquery  esta fuera del contexto de angularjs y no ejecuta `$apply()`, por lo que al ejecutar `$apply` forzamos manualmente a angular a actualizar la vista utilizando el `$digest()`.

En resumen. Elimina `$scope.$apply()` ya que `ngClick` lo esta ejecutando.

Comment: el problema que a loadOptions lo llamo asi: data-ng-init="loadOptions", necesito que llame a todos los metodos y una vez cargados actualice sus valores

Comment: Deberías actualizar tu pregunta con el contenido de `loadOptions()` para darte una respuesta mas completa. `ngInit` tambien ejecuta `$apply()` por lo que no es necesario llamarlo.

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo se relaciona un poco al funcionamiento de Javascript, otro poco a como funciona Angular. Como dice Einer, el $apply es invocado por Angular en todos los casos, y si intentás llamar a $apply dentro otro $apply, tira el error que estás teniendo.

En algunos casos es necesario volver a llamar el $apply ya que Angular puede no puede detectar cambios que se encuentran fuera de su scope.

Una solución para estos casos, es forzar a Javascript a que genere otra "ronda" o "turno" de ejecución.

En mi caso he tenido situaciones en las cuales necesitaba forzar un refresh y para esos casos, en angular 1 y 2, me ha servido hacer esto:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.name = "Timeout called!";
    });
  }, 0);
```

Esta nota (http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) me sirvió mucho para poder entender cuando y como usar el $apply de una forma que no se convierta en un anti-patrón en tu aplicación.

Te dejo un ejemplo de esta teoría aplicada: https://plnkr.co/edit/BZJH9qN6ux3rPRVgyJUk?p=preview

En el ejemplo vas a poder ver varias cosas, de cuando se actualiza y cuando no.

Una sola aclaración mas, siempre antes de aplicar este tipo de soluciones, revisa primero tu lógica, en mi caso, en 8 de cada 10, encontré otra solución que arreglaba el problema.

Segunda aclaración, en vez de setTimeout, conviene usar **$timeout** que ya tiene incluido un $apply en el código, pero en la respuesta quise demostrar un poco el porqué del error y como solucionarlo de acuerdo a sus causas.

Espero que sea de tu utilidad, en caso contrario, no dudes en volver a preguntar.

Comment: `setTimeout` no deberia ser usado cuando estas programando en un controlador angularjs. En su lugar deberia ser usado `$timeout` que es un servicio angular (wrapper de `setTimeout`)

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por la aclaración, en la respuesta lo había dejado aclarado, en el ante último párrafo, no lo puse como principal respuesta ya que quería demostrar la lógica detrás detrás de la solución, sino es solo una respuesta sin fundamento. Muchas gracias, saludos!

Comment: Cierto, no lei hasta el final :)

Comment: jajaja, no hay problemas, se hizo un poco larga la respuesta, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas segura de aplicar un `$scope.$apply();` es haciendolo dentro de un `$timeout`. Algo asi:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

De esta forma no obtendras el error que describes.